# Drupal 7 - Integrating Profile Taxonomy term with content type taxonomy terms using views

Tags: drupal-7, view, drupal-taxonomy

I set up a profile with a taxonomy and I'll call it "A". And "A" hase these terms:

Sales
Manager
Designer

And I've added the taxonomy field to a content type and to the user profiles. How am i able to tie these together in views? If a profile is designated as sales then that person will only see the nodes that are tied to the sales term.

Answer (score 0):

i think this could be useful. https://drupal.org/project/user_auto_tag

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.